# 4 figures in a row using ionic 2 bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic2

Im trying to make a product gallery, using ionic 2 bootstrap and html figure element. The problem is, at the 4 product, using col width-25, it breaks into a new row.

How can i make all the figures stay on the same line?

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row responsive-sm>
      <ion-col width-25>
        <figure>
          <img class="adjust-caption-image" src="{{ products[0].src }}" />
          <figcaption class="bg-lightgrey">
            <b class="tiny-text">{{ products[0].productName }}</b> <br />
            <div class="tiny-text font-darkgrey"><b>{{ products[0].supplierName }}</b></div> <br /> R$
            <div class="price-text">{{ products[0].price }}</div>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25>
        <figure>
          <img class="adjust-caption-image" src="{{ products[0].src }}" />
          <figcaption class="bg-lightgrey">
            <b class="tiny-text">{{ products[0].productName }}</b> <br />
            <div class="tiny-text font-darkgrey"><b>{{ products[0].supplierName }}</b></div> <br /> R$
            <div class="price-text">{{ products[0].price }}</div>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25>
        <figure>
          <img class="adjust-caption-image" src="{{ products[0].src }}" />
          <figcaption class="bg-lightgrey">
            <b class="tiny-text">{{ products[0].productName }}</b> <br />
            <div class="tiny-text font-darkgrey"><b>{{ products[0].supplierName }}</b></div> <br /> R$
            <div class="price-text">{{ products[0].price }}</div>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25>
        <figure>
          <img class="adjust-caption-image" src="{{ products[0].src }}" />
          <figcaption class="bg-lightgrey">
            <b class="tiny-text">{{ products[0].productName }}</b> <br />
            <div class="tiny-text font-darkgrey"><b>{{ products[0].supplierName }}</b></div> <br /> R$
            <div class="price-text">{{ products[0].price }}</div>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: which is the version of `ionic-angular`?

Comment: The `<br>` tag has no closing slash. Nor does the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 2 uses 12 columns bootstrap system. columns valid are ranging from 1 to 12, like `col-3 col-4 col-6 col-12`.

I had to use `col-3` instead of `col-25`.